# Primefaces Rendering issue

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, rendering

I have a probem with rendering a datatable properly with Primefaces: the rendering is just a plain text, without the normal Primefaces graphics (no alternate colour rows, ect).
I wanna just understand why, because all the other few pages are well rendered on my website.

Here the XHTML of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
    <h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="c" value="#{viewContattoBean.contatto}">  
        <p:column headerText="Nome">  
             <h:outputText value="#{c.contattoid}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Telefono">  
             <h:outputText value="#{c.numero}" />  
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>  
    </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RubricaWeb</display-name>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admins Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description />
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Users Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description />
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The problem, like I already sayd is that i visualize the table like plain text, but the content is correct (that's why i think is not usefull to show to you the managed bean).

thanks to all of you.

Comment: Do you have a theme applied? If you have no theme there is no styling what so ever on the datatable elements and I would be scared to know what that looked like. Look at themes in primefaces.

Comment: yes i installed it. in fact some pages i visualize normally (with a theme) but some others i see just a plain text

Answer (score 0):

In your ManagedBean you have the annotation `@Named` or `@ManagedBean`? It's necessary to use in any view.

The variable `contatto` in you ViewContattoBean is a List type? `#{viewContattoBean.contatto}`

The tag value of primefaces datatable need an list value or implementation from datamodel.

Comment: Contatto was an array. Now i trasformed it in list but seems that is an error, because it cannot deploy... The bean is a @ManagedBean... is it good right?! thanks

Comment: ok now it deploy with the list but it still don't work properly, the rendering is still a plain text while other pages are rendered with the theme